# Implications of field $\mathbf{F}$ with characteristic $0$.

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, rational-numbers

I am required to show that given any field $\mathbf{F}$ of characteristic zero the set $\mathbf{Q}$ of all rational numbers is a subset of $\mathbf{F}$.

The following is my attempt at the problem is it correct?

*Proof.* Since $\mathbf{F}$ is a field of characteristic zero it follows that 
$\forall n\in\mathbf{N}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}1\neq 0\right)$ consequently given any arbitrary rational number $\phi = \frac{p}{q}$ where $q\ne 0$ it follows that $p = (\sum_{j=1}^{p}1)\in\mathbf{F}$ and $q = (\sum_{j=1}^{q}1)\in\mathbf{F}$ since $q\neq 0$ we can deduce using the axioms of a field that $\frac{1}{q}\in\mathbf{F}$ and by extension reason that $\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbf{F}$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: This in itself shows that there is an element in $\mathbf{F}$ that it would be very natural to identify to the rational $\frac pq$, but it doesn't quite explain why this identification is a field homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\hookrightarrow\mathbf{F}$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Could you please explain your point further

Comment: The multiplicative identity element that you call $1_\mathbf{F}$ in $\mathbf{F}$ is not (necessarily) the usual number $1$. Just like $1_\mathbf{F}+\ldots +1_\mathbf{F}$ ($p$ times) **is** not $p\in \mathbb{N}$. But there is a natural map that identifies them.
Technically you still have to explain why this map respects the operations of fields (maps a sum to a sum, etc.). And also technically the statement that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\mathbf{F}$ is wrong. $\mathbb{Q}$ is only *isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbf{F}$*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems (some of which were mentioned in the comments):

1. The statement is false. The best you can do is to prove that $\mathbf F$ contains a subfield which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$.
2. You assert that you found a way of associating each element of $\mathbb Q$ with an element of $\mathbf F$. No, you did not. To each *representation* of a *positive* rational number as $\frac pq$ (with $p,q\in\mathbb N$) you associated an element of $\mathbf F$. But you did *not* prove that, say $\frac23$ and $\frac69$ are associated with the same number (they should, since they are the same rational number).
3. What about the negative rationals?
4. You still have to proved that this association is a field homomorphism (it is).